# NVD3 D3.JS Issue. control Labels stop working after this: .controlLabels({"grouped":"Agrupadas","stacked":"Apiladas"});

Tags: javascript, d3.js, translation, nvd3.js

I have been using this function to translate the control labels.

```
.controlLabels({"grouped":"Agrupadas","stacked":"Apiladas"});
```

It works, the labels change just fine, but, they stop working as well, that's the issue.

What could be the problem?

This is my graph http://codepen.io/neonpulp/pen/zBRdYz and below is the code too.

```
<script>
var long_short_data_plancalair = [
    {
        key: '1er trimestre',
        color: "#438da7",
        values: [
            {
                "label" : "Mapas de Calor Elaborados" ,
                "value" : 15
            }                                                       
        ]
    },
    {
        key: '2do trimestre',
        color: "#d86d18",
        values: [
            {
                "label" : "Mapas de Calor Elaborados" ,
                "value" : 50
            }                                                                                                               
        ]
        
    }
];


var chart;
nv.addGraph(function() {
    chart = nv.models.multiBarHorizontalChart()
        .x(function(d) { return d.label })
        .y(function(d) { return d.value })
        .duration(250)
        .margin({left: 295})
        .stacked(true)
        
        .controlLabels({"grouped":"Agrupadas","stacked":"Apiladas"});
        
    chart.yAxis.tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));
    
    chart.yAxis.tickFormat(function(d) { return d3.format(',f')(d)+ '%' });

    chart.yAxis.axisLabel('');
    chart.xAxis.axisLabel('').axisLabelDistance(20);
    

    d3.select('#chart-plancalair svg')
        .datum(long_short_data_plancalair)
        .call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

    chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) { nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e)); });
    chart.state.dispatch.on('change', function(state){
        nv.log('state', JSON.stringify(state));
    });
    return chart;
});

</script>
```